# gradient bar with line

Tags: android, android-layout

[image]

I am trying to get gradient bar as in image 
i got gradient bar but  how can i get white lines on that gradient bar at 25%,50%

```
    <layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
<item>

    <shape
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:shape="rectangle"   >

        <solid
            android:width="1dp"
            android:color="#2B2B2D" >
        </solid>

        <stroke
            android:width="1dp"
            android:color="#666666" >
        </stroke>

        <padding
            android:left="2dp"
            android:top="2dp"
            android:right="2dp"
            android:bottom="2dp"    >
        </padding>

        <corners
            android:radius="2dp"   >
        </corners>

    </shape>
</item>
    <item>
        <shape
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:shape="rectangle"   >



            <padding
                android:left="5dp"
                android:top="5dp"
                android:right="5dp"
                android:bottom="5dp"    >
            </padding>

            <corners
                android:radius="2dp"   >
            </corners>

                <gradient
                    android:angle="180"
                    android:endColor="#11B24A"
                    android:centerColor="#fec804"
                    android:startColor="#E3434B"
                    android:type="linear" />

        </shape>
    </item>

</layer-list>
```

i used above code as background for imageview
i can get line using view with height 8dp and width 1dp how can i place them at exactly at 25% 50%..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a hacky way of doing this :

**Code :**

---

gradient_bar.xml (same as yours)

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item>

        <shape
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:shape="rectangle"   >

            <solid
                android:width="1dp"
                android:color="#2B2B2D" >
            </solid>

            <stroke
                android:width="1dp"
                android:color="#666666" >
            </stroke>

            <padding
                android:left="2dp"
                android:top="2dp"
                android:right="2dp"
                android:bottom="2dp"    >
            </padding>

            <corners
                android:radius="2dp"   >
            </corners>

        </shape>
    </item>
    <item>
        <shape
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:shape="rectangle"   >



            <padding
                android:left="5dp"
                android:top="5dp"
                android:right="5dp"
                android:bottom="5dp"    >
            </padding>

            <corners
                android:radius="2dp"   >
            </corners>

            <gradient
                android:angle="180"
                android:endColor="#11B24A"
                android:centerColor="#fec804"
                android:startColor="#E3434B"
                android:type="linear" />

        </shape>
    </item>

</layer-list>
```

---

white_line.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <View
        android:layout_width="1dp"
        android:layout_margin="2dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:background="@android:color/white"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

---

no_white_line.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <View
        android:layout_width="1dp"
        android:layout_margin="2dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

---

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/gradient_bar"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="10dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true">

        <include layout="@layout/white_line"/>
        <include layout="@layout/white_line"/>
        <include layout="@layout/white_line"/>
        <include layout="@layout/white_line"/>
        <include layout="@layout/no_white_line"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

---

Output :

[image: gradient bar with white lines]

---

Hope it helps !